# Do very tiny-value capacitors still block DC?

Tags: capacitor, dc

In a simple circuit with a AA cell and every capacitor I can find, the capacitor charges to equal the battery voltage almost immediately and blocks DC entirely.  This is not unexpected, but it led me to wonder...  Is there any value of capacitor so small that the DC would continue to flow through/past it?

[image]

A quick search shows that 0.1pF is just about the smallest value available.  Below that, the capacitor's effect is so similar to parasitic capacitance that it's foolish to try selling them.

Were there a commercially-available capacitor a tenth, or even a millionth, of that value, would it still block DC?

Comment: A small value of capacitance is similar to an open circuit, so no, DC will not flow.

Comment: Other way around. Try an infinite capacitor. But to see it block DC you'll have to wait infinitely long.

Answer (score 5):

All capacitors are essentially an open circuit and stop the flow of DC current flow.

Answer (score 3):

The smaller the value, the *more* a capacitor blocks low frequencies. If you want a cap to pass very low frequencies, you have to make it very large, i.e. multiple farads. If you make the capacitor infinite, it'll even pass DC. However, any *finite* capacitor will never pass DC (otherwise you wouldn't be able to charge it).

You most likely already have an infinite capacitor at home: It's called a wire.

As was pointed out by user1850479 already, a 0 pF capacitor is just a perfect open circuit. No current can ever flow through it.

Comment: A wire behaves very unlike an infinite capacitor.

Comment: @TypeIA A capacitor has a voltage V=Q/C across it; if C is infinite, V is zero. Therefore an infinite capacitor never has any voltage across it - it behaves exactly like an ideal wire (it is, in fact, *identical* to an ideal wire from a mathematical standpoint). A non-ideal infinite capacitor has ESR and ESL in addition to its infinite capacitance, making it exactly equivalent to a real-life wire.

Comment: Thank you, I considered this and researched and although counterintuitive (at least to me) I see you're completely right. I'll leave my comment as context for your reply, but I stand corrected, with apologies.

Answer (score 2):

**By definition** a capacitor blocks DC.  If you have some physical thing that was billed to you as a "capacitor", then *to the extent* that it blocks DC, it's a capacitor.

Note this doesn't have to be something commercially available -- if you have two adjacent pads on a PCB, you can point to them and say "that's a capacitor" and the above statement is true.

Note that, in general, real-world capacitors don't *completely* block DC.  There's always some leakage, somewhere.  Even if you got a "perfect" capacitor from some multidimensional, god-like alien, when you soldered it onto a mundane board from this universe, the board would leak current around it.  And if you get an electrolytic capacitor, there will be leakage -- very much more so if it's an aluminum electrolytic.